# AIR application exit code

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I understand in AS3, you can create a Native Process, and once that process is complete, you can get the exitCode from NativeProcessExitEvent, which is just the exit code that native process returned to the OS. Is there anyway to set the exit code for when the AIR application closes? We have one application triggering this AIR application, and it is waiting for an exit code from the AIR application.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are looking for this function :

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit( 1 );
```

Where 1 is the exit code

Comment: exit(1) will attempt to restart the AIR app, I tried this already. Any other code will barf out some runtime error